# Failed to create repository via gitlab-shell

Tags: gitlab

I just installed Gitlab via omnibus package on CentOS 7.

When I try to create a new project with the web interface I got the following error :

```
The form contains the following error:

Failed to create repository via gitlab-shell
```

In the logs :

**gitlab-rails**

```
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "project"=>{"namespace_id"=>"1", "path"=>"Extrapack-MonFatec", "import_url"=>"[FILTERED]", "description"=>"", "visibility_level"=>"0"}}
Unable to save project. Error: Failed to create repository
Completed 200 OK in 1049ms (Views: 157.3ms | ActiveRecord: 21.0ms)
```

**gitlab-shell**

```
I, [2016-07-11T13:40:42.549484 #31319]  INFO -- : Adding project root/Extrapack-MonFatec.git at </var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/root/Extrapack-MonFatec.git>.
```

**gitlab:check**

```
Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 3.0.0 ? ... OK (3.0.0)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
hooks directories in repos are links: ... can't check, you have no projects
Running /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files: 
    /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories: OK
    /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
Send ping to redis server: gitlab-shell self-check successful

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking Reply by email ...

Reply by email is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking Reply by email ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Git configured with autocrlf=input? ... yes
Database config exists? ... yes
All migrations up? ... yes
Database contains orphaned GroupMembers? ... no
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Uploads directory setup correctly? ... skipped (no tmp uploads folder yet)
Init script exists? ... skipped (omnibus-gitlab has no init script)
Init script up-to-date? ... skipped (omnibus-gitlab has no init script)
projects have namespace: ... can't check, you have no projects
Redis version >= 2.8.0? ... yes
Ruby version >= 2.1.0 ? ... yes (2.1.8)
Your git bin path is "/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git"
Git version >= 2.7.3 ? ... yes (2.7.4)
Active users: 1

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

I don't know what's going on ... 
Do you have any idea ? I have checked every related subjects in forum, I didn't see any solutions.

Thank you !

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the best solution, but I simply restored from a previous GitLab backup via:

`bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:restore RAILS_ENV=production BACKUP=timestamp_of_your_backup`

Doing so reverted whatever setting I messed up, and allowed me to create a project via the web interface.

I'm running GitLab 2.9 (installed from source) on RHEL 7.3.